# how to OrderBy length(column_name) using JPA Criteria Builder

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I want to create a natural order sort :

I have string valued column like : { a-demo-1, a-demo-2, a-demo-10,a-demo-3}.

I know that:

1)*Order by length first of the column and*

2)*Order by the same column will work.*

consider this PostgreSql:

```
select id, name from table_name
order by length(name), name;
```

This is working, but I am stuck at converting it into criteria query.

I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
criteriaQuery.orderBy( // Order by
     criteriaBuilder.desc( // Descending order
         criteriaBuilder.length( // By length
              root.get("columnName")))); // Column name
```